# "deque iterator not dereferencable" at queue.front() when queue is not empty

Tags: c++, queue, std

I am sure this question gets asked a lot - in fact i found 10+ answers while googling the problem. But all of them pointed out not to call queue.front() when the queue is empty.

I have the following code:

```
std::queue<Message*> MessageQ;    //declaring  the queue
//...
MessageQ.push(Msg);  //filling the Queue
//...
if (!MessageQ.empty())
{
    Message* ToReturn = MessageQ.front();
    MessageQ.pop();
    return ToReturn;
}
return 0;
```

and i get the "deque iterator not dereferencable" error at the .front() line.

what other problems might trigger such an error when using queue.front()?

I even tried commenting the front line out - the message gets popped like it should.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Your question would benefit from a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please create one so we can better help you. You might even find the answer yourself while creating it.

Comment: How is `MessageQ` declared in your code exactly?

Comment: what is the type of MessageQ? what type of item it contains?

Comment: If `Message` is an iterator, don't declare `Message * ToReturn`, but just `Message ToReturn`

Comment: @vsoftco: I suspect it's a `std::queue<Message*>`, and that `Message` is not an iterator.

Comment: Are you pushing stuff into the queue in one thread, and popping them in another?

Comment: You are somehow invalidating the iterator to the beginning of the list (see @Praetorian). Please post your code.

Comment: looks like OP is not as much interested to get help as we are to provide help. No reply to any comment!!!

Comment: Sorry guys, i was at dinner. MessageQ is defined as "std::queue<Message*> MessageQ;", where Message is a simple class I defined to hold MessageData. I fill the Queue with "MessageQ.push(Msg);" where Msg is a pointer to a Msg-struct I fill before queueing it.

Comment: Can you show creation of Msg?

Comment: Are you using any multithreading in this program at all?

Comment: this is my creation code:

Message *Msg = new Message();      Msg->MessageLength = msglength;      Msg->MessageType = Metadata[0];  
Msg->ChecksumTrue = (checksumtest == checksum);
MessageQ.push(Msg);

No, I dont use multithreading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sorry, it was a dumb mistake on my part. I had a memset() somewhere in the constructor, which overwrote the queue with the data of an empty stack, as i changed the type this afternoon.

Lesson learned, and thanks for Your answers!

Comment: The mistake is using `memset` instead of [`std::fill`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill) or [`std::fill_n`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill_n).